# How can I have a full or in Ruby regular expression?

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I want to check if a non letter/number or \W is at the beginning or the end of a variable, just a true or false. The usual code that I would use would be:

```
str.match( /^\W) || str.match( /\W$/ )
```

Of course, one could accomplish that using mutltiple ways, such as:

```
[ /^\W/, /\W$/ ].index{ | regy | str.match( regy ) }
```

however, I would like to know if there is a way to this in one regular expression. I.e.

```
str.match( regy ) # the single regexp handles the or part on it's own.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Use the `|` in regex:

```
/^\W|\W$/
```